# Join three different forms into one and get result in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-bookings, google-ajax-search-api

I am a newbie on WordPress, hope someone helps me.
My question is that, I have three different plugins, ajax search pro, Geo my wp, and woocommerce booking filter and I have to merge these three plugins into one as shown in the image. so the customer will search the product using ajax search pro, then select location using geo my wp and then select date from booking filter and last just press button to get result on the next page. Anyone, please help me... Thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l5j9.png)

Comment: If you use shortcodes, then you need to work more on the styles to float the input groups, unless you really want to play with the template files for all the plugins and create a custom template which will take a huge time to achieve

Comment: I have designed the template. Now i have to merge the functionality of these three